# Failed to create EGL context due to EGL_BAD_ALLOC while rendering in webrtc flutter

Tags: android, flutter, webrtc, rendering

In my case I have implemented Flutter webrtc for video streaming with one to many and many to many both case and after live video more than 11 time my apk is getting crash.

Video streaming is working proper in AndroidRtc but facing this issue in flutter.

Help me with this case if anybody have faced this issue.

Here are the crash i am getting in my case:

```
org.webrtc.Logging: SurfaceTextureHelper: decoder-texture-thread create failure
SurfaceTextureHelper: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to create EGL context: 0x3003
E/org.webrtc.Logging: SurfaceTextureHelper: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to create EGL context: 0x3003
at org.webrtc.EglBase14Impl.createEglContext(EglBase14Impl.java:282)
at org.webrtc.EglBase14Impl.(EglBase14Impl.java:78)
at org.webrtc.EglBase.createEgl14(EglBase.java:215)
at org.webrtc.EglBase.create(EglBase.java:158)
at org.webrtc.SurfaceTextureHelper.(SurfaceTextureHelper.java:187)
```